# Bullet points in Warning Message box for a web page

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to add Bullet points for the warning/Alert message box for a webpage using HTML and Java Script? If not, what would be the best possbile way to create one of those?

The message box should have the below properties:

1. Warning Image
2. Message box header
3. Bullet points listing summary
4. Accept and Reject button

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There *may* be a way to sneak bullet points into an `alert()` box using some Unicode shenanigans, but in general, these boxes can not be styled. Individually labeled buttons are totally out of the question.

You would have to use a custom-made library like [JQUery UI dialogs.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) Alternatively, [here](http://theinfiniteloopblog.com/tag/custom-javascript-dialog-boxes/) is a more light-weight tutorial on building custom alert boxes.

Answer (score 17):

Just an update on this, you can create a bullet in a JavaScript alert box, you just need to use `\u2022`, so your script would be something like this (`\n` is a line break):

```
alert("!!! WARNING !!!\n\nHeader\n\u2022Point1\n\u2022Point2")
```

This will display (in an alert box):

> !!! WARNING !!!
>
> Header
>
> - Point1
> - Point2

Answer (score 5):

The standard `confirm` function cannot do all this; instead, you can use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to develop a custom alert box. I may develop it using jQuery colorbox. or jQuery UI Dialogs